# net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.ReportExpressionEvaluationData

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a problem, I have an old Jasper template that generates an invoice and is launched by a java application. The issue is that when compiling with some new modifications it gives me the following error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Class not found when loading object from file : C:\...
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.doWork(SessionImpl.java:1987)
... 16 more

Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Class not found when loading object from file : C:\....
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:105)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.ReportExpressionEvaluationData
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ContextClassLoaderObjectInputStream.java:75)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at java.util.HashMap.readObject(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor17.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:97)
... 19 more
```

I have noticed that when compiling it modifies the expressions used in the old template. I think the error is that, in compile options I am choosing the old version of the project, but it still makes modifications.

I have tried changing the version of the template